# Simulator of devices for testing

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp

Does anyone know the simulator of devices (Generator, Battery or Solar) which supports DNP3 and Modbus protocols?

I'm implementing an application which reads data from devices via DNP3 or Modbus protocol. Because I do not have real devices now so I need the simulator for testing.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[ModRSsim](http://www.plcsimulator.org/Home) can be used to simulate a Modbus slave.